# What does 15mm margin in Microsoft Office Word mean?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using `Microsoft Word 2013`, and know how to set `margins`. The issue I'm just facing is that I need to set the margins to `15mm`, while in the program I can see the margins set with values such as `1`. Is that in `inch`? And, in this case, it would be a conversion from `mm` to `inch`?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 inch = 25.4 mm

Comment: you can assign mm as the unit of measure in your margins.  If I set my margins to 15mm and hit ok it converts that to inches but it's still 15mm.  It shows .59".  refer to Brian's comment, above.

Answer (score 2):

The units that are used for displaying measurements is set within "Preferences - General". The choices there are: inches; centimeters; millimeters; points; picas. 
However, irrespective of the choice made there, you can enter margins in any units you like e.g. even if preferences are set to inches, for a roughly 3/4 inch margin you can enter:
.75
.75 in
.75"
1.9 cm
19 mm
54 pt
4.5 pi

Spaces between digits and units are ignored, leading 0's are optional. (i.e. "0.75in" is same as ".75 in")
When you have saved and closed the dialog box setting margins, the next time you open it, the margins you set will display in the units set in preferences irrespective of the units used when they were entered.